# How to have one of the columns of my main Select Statement query of one table, as an output from another Select statement from another table?

Tags: sql, mysql, output

Example:

I want the *COL3* replaced with the Select statement form TABLE B as below in my original Select Statement of TABLE A:

```
Select COL1, COL2, <*COL3*> from TableA;
```

COL3  => (Select Sum(COL2) from TableB Group by COl1 and order by COL1)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using  some subqueries

```
select t2.col1, t1.col3, t3.col2
from TableA t2
inner join  (
    Select col1, Sum(COL2) col3 
    from TableB Group by COl1 and order by COL1
from TableA ) t1 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
inner join (
     select col1, col2
) t3 on t3.col1 = t2.col1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I got bit confused with the t1,t2,t3 with col1, col2, col3. I have only two tables. So t1 and t2(or Table A and Table B). And col 1, col2 is from t1. The placeholder <col3> should be replaced with the output from: Select Sum(COL2) from TableB Group by col1 and order by col1 ASC;

Comment: The query in my answer  use subquerys result as dinamic table in join with fisical table  t2 is tha table name alias for TableA, t1 is the table name alias for a first subquery result  and t3 is another table name alias for a second subquery ..  you should take a look at table name alias and subqueries join

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins, if you have something common between the two tables.
For example:

```
SELECT T1.COL1, T1.COL2, 
T2.COL3 FROM T1 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT COL3 FROM T) T2
ON T1.COL1 = T2.COL3
```